# Magento 2 Navigation - Products Categories

Tags: magento2, navigation

I'm using magento 2 , and I'm trying to create the product categories this way : basicly I want a parent category called CLOTHING that will appear in the navigation , and a subcategory called DRESSES in the CLOTHING category , and at the same level as CLOTHING I also want to see DRESSES , as it is a category , even if is a subcategory , and I want it to link same as clothing/dresses.. I don't know if I explained myself well..

Answer (score 0):

So DRESSES would be a subcategory of CLOTHING, but you also have a top level category of DRESSES?

Are they both the same?

If so, you should be able to set them both to the same URL Key?

Comment: yes , they will be both the same , is just that I want dresses also as a top level category  but I don't want to create another top category , as dresses is already a subcategory of clothing.. how do I set both on the same url key ? or do I need to create also a top category called dresses ,  with their subcategories , same as clothing/dresses ?

Comment: I think (if I understand correctly), that you need to create both categories in the category structure in Products\ Categories\  (Admin), just make sure that you add the same URL Key.

Comment: So I need to create DRESSES and his subcategories 2 times ? One as subcategory of CLOTHING , and another one as top category by his own ?